# Running an uber jar from sbt assembly results in error: Could not find or load main class

Tags: java, jar, classloader, sbt-assembly

I have a spark job packaged as an uber-jar using the sbt assembly plugin.
The `build.sbt` specifies a runnable main to be the target of the resulting uber-jar

```
mainClass in assembly := Some("com.foo.Bar")
```

After the assembly is correctly created, running the intended command:

```
java -jar assembly.jar
```

results in

> Error: Could not find or load main class com.foo.Bar

Using the an alternative method, like `java -cp assembly.jar com.foo.Bar` gives the same error message.

Then, I extracted the contents of the uber-jar in a new directory. I can see my `com/foo/` directory and the `Bar.class` file. 
From the root of the extracted directory I tried:

```
java -cp . com.foo.Bar
```

and I get a correct result.

Further trying to find the reason of the error, I tried:

```
java -verbose -jar assembly.jar
```

I can see the java core classes being loaded, but I don't see any of my packaged classes being loaded.

What can possibly be wrong here?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

After an extensive investigation (read: pulling hairs out), it turns out that this behavior is the result of a rogue `INDEX.LIST` from one of the flattened jar files landing in the `META-INF` directory of the resulting uber-jar.

Following the [JAR file spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html#JAR_Manifest), the `INDEX.LIST`, if present, dictates what packages from the Jar file are to be loaded.

To avoid this, we updated the `mergeStrategy` with a rule to avoid any pollution of the resulting `META-INF` directory:

```
case PathList("META-INF", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.discard
```

This fixed the issue and returned my sanity.

---

Update:

After some extra searching, it turns out that the [default merge strategy](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly#merge-strategy) takes proper care of `INDEX.LIST`. This answer applies when the customized merge strategy contains cases that handle the `META-INF` `pathSpec`

Comment: This also fixes another related problem, I can use the fatjar to bring dependencies into spark-shell. I can run the import statements. But then I get a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError when I try to actually use them. Maddening!

Comment: You saved my life. I was literally going insane. I don't want to imagine what you went through to discover it on your own.

Comment: I did not understand the "update", though first part did work.